# animate the table rows to slide out or fade in?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-animate

I stumbled upon this plugin

https://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/customization.html

the problem is, everything is in `<tr>`s and I fear you cannot animate them?

Is there really no way? CSS or javascript wise.

e.g. I want to animate a tables tr elements.

Comment: Can you specify which part exactly is the animation you are looking for? I cannot find any sliding out or fading in.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one solution could be like that :

```js
var animate = function(evt) {
  //we go to the 'tr' tag
  $el = $(evt.currentTarget).parent().parent();
  
  //we hide the 'td's tag 
  $el.find('td').hide(333 , function(){
    // we reduce the height of 'tr' tag
    $el.animate({height : 0} , 777)
  });
  

}
$('button').click(animate);
```

```css
table {
  border: solid 1px #AAA;
  padding: 3px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
td {
  height: 50px;
  margin : 3px;
  min-width : 50px;
  border: solid 1px orange;
}
tr {
  height : 55px;
  padding : 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td><td>b</td><td><button>hide</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td><td>b</td><td><button>hide</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td><td>b</td><td><button>hide</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```